# Transmission top bracket snapped when inflating tyres

Tags: tires, transmission, micra

Clutch was replaced in my 2005 nissan micra about 3 months ago, today I inflated my front tyre to specification pressure (2.3 bar) and immediately after driving I felt something was broken so I checked and the top supportive bracket for the tranmission had completely snapped leaving the engine and tranmission drooping far down under it.
What could have caused this? 
Could the increased tyre pressure have forced it to snap due to its age or was it really just a coincidence?

Comment: It seems much more likely that the engine mount or transmission mount was broken or damaged during the clutch replacement.  I just can't imagine any scenario where tire inflation could do anything like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the transmission bracket do not break as a result of changing tire pressure.

It is more likely this is a result of not properly adjusting the engine mounts and transmission bracket when your clutch was replaced,or the engine mounts might have started to fail as a result of wear.

I think you should take a look at the engine mounts to see if the rubber is damaged and they needs to be replaced,the transmission bracket might get overloaded if the engine mounts starts to fail.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The OP's question is roughly the same as asking *"I just totally replaced the roof on my house, and then I watered the flowers. There's a leak in my bedroom, did it happen because I watered the flowers?"* The leak is almost certainly related to replacing the roof, not watering the flowers! Something went wrong during the clutch replacement. Maybe an engine mount was removed and not replaced correctly (or at all). All the load goes on the transmission mount, and it snaps. I've seen worse.

Comment: So far this seems like the most likely case but i find it hard to believe that it was running flawlessly for close to 4 months, and snapped instantly after increasing tyre pressure. Obviously something wasn't done correctly during the repairs but my question was really whether what was done wrong could be for example suspension no longer being able to compensate for the wheels being forced further from the ground putting all of the pressure on the mount.

Comment: @non - I would bet it was on its way out after the work was done and this was just the final straw. It's time was done. Things wear out, especially engine/tranny mounts. Your vehicle is ~15yo ... mechanical things don't last forever. If you replace the mount and it happens again, then I'd suggest you have a larger issue.  As trond stated, the difference in tire pressure is not going to be the contributing factor here.